# How to enable "When app in use" in CLLocationManager in iOS 8

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I just became aware of a new privacy option for Location Service in iOS 8 which allows the user to select "When app in use" as privacy option.

My application needs to go back to iOS 7, and I can't figure out how to make this option available for my application. Currently it just says "Always/Never"

I am not doing anything special in the code. Location Services are started using

`startUpdatingLocation`

when in the foreground, and

`startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`

when in the background.

I also tried implementing

`-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status`

to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is a plist value you need to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With iOS 8 you must add a new value to your plist, either NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription or NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription. If you want a specific message to show when the alert is displayed to the user, you can set the string as the value to the location key.

Also you must add this code to actually ask the user the permission, switch out the function with whichever key you used in your plist.

```
#pragma message ("iOS 8 Support for location updating")
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]){
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}
```

More information https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/